# Issue with ucm prediction

Tags: r

I am using ucm in R to fit a time series model, but am unable to make predictions from it. Here is my code.

```
fitucm<- ucm(formula = x~0, data = x, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE)
fitucm
plot(x, ylab = "Sales")
lines(fitucm$s.level, col = "blue")
legend("topright", legend = c("sales","S_level"), col = c("black","blue"), lty = 1)
predict(fitucm$model, n.ahead = 12)
```

I got the following error.

```
Error in is.SSModel(model, na.check = TRUE, return.logical = FALSE) : 
  Model is not a proper object of class 'SSModel'. Check dimensions of system matrices.
```

So I did

```
  newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0( "SSMtrend(1, Q =  list(fitucm$est.var.level))",
                                              "+ SSMcycle(365, Q = fitucm$est.var.cycle)")), H = fitucm$irr.var, data=x)
    pred<-predict(fitucm$model, newdata=newdata1)
```

But even this is not working. How should I predict using the ucm model?

`dput(x)` returns

structure(c(305.782684, 626.360641, 346.231655, 393.29374, 338.899657, 
580.365259, 442.367196, 403.321188, 286.18491, 563.349778, 346.744479, 
352.020911, 427.071993, 293.656763, 517.329794, 352.945061, 297.888494, 
284.293553, 392.695937, 300.916378, 341.221086, 311.006093, 326.163204, 
477.350303, 281.105887, 384.553564, 293.733286, 275.859299, 366.864272, 
268.904152, 302.751203, 317.405698, 342.042525, 423.322273, 404.699796, 
316.475645, 338.550231, 342.17192, 386.808382, 352.555864, 376.145766, 
362.846193, 361.29863, 330.07548, 295.976383, 284.547718, 363.381609, 
358.46016, 242.9839, 401.398545, 271.791979, 287.798405, 276.846896, 
283.550623, 403.772366, 521.261135, 361.753866), .Tsp = c(1, 
2.07323750855578, 52.1785714285714), class = "ts")

Comment: Can you post the output (or part of it) of `dput(x)`? I have run your code with `x <- ts(rnorm(1000))` and no error appears

Comment: Done. I edited the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've debugged a little the problem and it's something with the frequency of the data that makes the `is.SSModel()` function to crash. If you use `x <- ts(x)` before training the model to reset the frequency then the prediction is done correctly. The complete code to make the prediction:

```
freqx <- frequency(x)
x <- ts(x)
fitucm <- ucm(formula = x~0, data = x, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE)
x2 <- ts(c(x,predict(fitucm$model, n.ahead = 12)), frequency = freqx)
print(x2)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 2.30321697467488 
Frequency = 52.1785714285714 
 [1] 305.7827 626.3606 346.2317 393.2937 338.8997 580.3653 442.3672 403.3212
 [9] 286.1849 563.3498 346.7445 352.0209 427.0720 293.6568 517.3298 352.9451
[17] 297.8885 284.2936 392.6959 300.9164 341.2211 311.0061 326.1632 477.3503
[25] 281.1059 384.5536 293.7333 275.8593 366.8643 268.9042 302.7512 317.4057
[33] 342.0425 423.3223 404.6998 316.4756 338.5502 342.1719 386.8084 352.5559
[41] 376.1458 362.8462 361.2986 330.0755 295.9764 284.5477 363.3816 358.4602
[49] 242.9839 401.3985 271.7920 287.7984 276.8469 283.5506 403.7724 521.2611
[57] 361.7539 347.2653 348.2428 349.2203 350.1979 351.1754 352.1529 353.1305
[65] 354.1080 355.0855 356.0631 357.0406 358.0181
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How did you figure out that x had to be converted to a ts again?

Comment: It's not that x had to be converted because it is already a `ts` object but I tried your code with a timeserie of frequency = 1 and it gave no error. `x <- ts(x)` was my first idea to reset the frequency of your timeserie.

Comment: Do you mind looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60846188/ucm-model-in-r-throws-error-error-in-ssmcycle? Thank you for your earlier help.

Comment: I have just posted an answer, hope it helps!