# ucm model in R throws error "error in SSMCycle"

Tags: r

I am trying to run the unobserved components model in R with a certain data set. Here is the code.

```
   library(rucm)
reg<-data.frame(a=c(3,7,2,4,8,3,7,7,5,9),b=c(9,5,6,2,1,7,3,5,8,4))
reg<-as.matrix(reg)
h<-4
x1=ts(c(5979511 ,13608701,  6193970 , 5269967 ,10424370 , 9504397),frequency=365.25/52)
u<-ucm_Forecast(x1,h,reg)

#d<-cbind(as.data.frame(x1),reg[1:length(x1),])

ucm_Forecast=function(x,h,xreg){

print(x)
  if (ncol(xreg)>=1){


      x<-x/10000
      d<-cbind(as.data.frame(x),xreg[1:length(x),])

    fit_ucm<- ucm(formula = x~a+b, data = d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE)

    print("right before predict")
    print(xreg)

    indep <- paste(names(d)[2:3], collapse= "+")
    newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0("rep(NA,h) ~ ", indep, "+ SSMtrend(1, Q =  list(fit_ucm$est.var.level))",
                                          "+ SSMcycle(365, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle)")), H = fit_ucm$irr.var, data=as.data.frame(xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),]))
    fcst<-predict(fit_ucm$model, newdata=newdata1)

    #fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, xreg=xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),])
  print("right after predict")
      fcst<-fcst*10000
    print(fcst)

  } else {

    x=ts(filter(Model_Dataset,Category==Cat,Date<FcstDate)$`Gross Sales`)
    x<-x*10000
    x<-x/10000
    x<-ts(x)

    x
    fitucm<- ucm(formula = x~0, data = x, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE)
    fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, n.ahead = h)
    fcst<-fcst*10000
    fcst
  }

  return(fcst)
}
```

I get the error below, corresponding to the statement and I don't know what it means because it is some internal call.

```
  newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0("rep(NA,h) ~ ", indep, "+ SSMtrend(1, Q =  list(fit_ucm$est.var.level))",
                                              "+ SSMcycle(365, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle)")), H = fit_ucm$irr.var, data=as.data.frame(xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),]))



  Error in SSMcycle(period = 365, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle, index = 1L,  : 
  Misspecified Q, argument Q must be (p x p) matrix, (p x p x 1), or (p x p x n) array where m is the number of time series.
Called from: SSMcycle(period = 365, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle, index = 1L, 
    n = 4L)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Your error is not reproducible with what you have provided. Restart R, clear your workspace, and try again.

Comment: @Edward  I edited the question. After cleaning the workspace and restarting R I am getting a different error.

Comment: The problem lies in the `cbind(x,xreg[1:length(x),])` part. Since `x` is a time series, this is a bit weird. Try `cbind(x = as.vector(x),xreg[1:length(x),])`

Comment: @Bas I now get this error after implementing your suggestion. Error in data[, as.character(dep.var)] : subscript out of bounds
Called from: is.data.frame(x)

Comment: @Bas I could fix the error but now I get another one while predicting using the model. Please see my edit.

Comment: Seems that the whole code is riddled with errors.

Comment: @Edward Why do you say that? I could run it. It's getting stuck at the point of prediction. Let me know what errors you are seeing. I did re-start R as you indicated. It's work in progress..It's not running smoothly yet.

Comment: Since your first post, I have seen  no less than three separate errors. What's the bet that after fixing the next one, there is yet another one?

Comment: The value of the `newdata` argument has to be an object of class "SSModel".

Comment: @Edward There is no assurance that there will be no errors because this is work in progress. I am working on this in parallel and am editing the question as I make progress. You will see now that I have posted a different error, but the problem is still in the "predict" part.

Comment: @Edward I realized from an old stack overflow answer that newdata has to be of type SSModel. But I am still getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope all of you are doing ok with lockdowns (writing from Spain). I'm not really sure about the predictions I have gotten, but here is what I have understood debugging your code.

In this line of code, creating the `fit_ucm` model:

```
fit_ucm<- ucm(formula = x~a+b, data = d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE)
```

you are creating a model with only a level component and a slope component. However, when creating the `SSModel` you are trying to introduce a periodic component using the `SSMcycle()` function. This raises an error because it does not find the `fit_ucm$est.var.cycle` component of the previous model because it does not exist (remember that you only have trained a level + slope model). Moreover, when you are creating the trend component, you are only modelling the level of the `ucm` model, so you have forgotten the `slope`. Once I've debugged all that, I can propose two solutions:

1. Erase the cycle component of the `SSModel()` function and create the model only with the level and slope component. Reading the documentation this can be done with the `SSMregression()` or the `SSMtrend()` functions. Due to my inability to use `SSMregression()` and reading the documentation of `SSMtrend()`, the code to create the `SSModel` **with only level and slope component** is:

```
newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0("rep(NA,h) ~ ", indep,
                                      "+ SSMtrend(2, Q = list(fit_ucm$est.var.level,
                                                              fit_ucm$est.var.slope))")
                                   ), 
                        H = fit_ucm$irr.var, 
                        data = as.data.frame(xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),]))
```

2. Introduce the `cycle` component in the `ucm` model and create the `SSModel` **with level, slope and cycle components**. This can be done with the following code:

```
fit_ucm <- ucm(formula = x~a+b, data = d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 365.25/52)
newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0("rep(NA,h) ~ ", indep,
                                      "+ SSMtrend(2, Q =  list(fit_ucm$est.var.level,
                                                               fit_ucm$est.var.slope))",
                                      "+ SSMcycle(365.25/52, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle)")
                                   ), 
                        H = fit_ucm$irr.var, 
                        data=as.data.frame(xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),]))
```

Using the lattest proposed solution, the final code would be:

```
library(rucm)
reg<-data.frame(a=c(3,7,2,4,8,3,7,7,5,9),b=c(9,5,6,2,1,7,3,5,8,4))
reg<-as.matrix(reg)
h<-4
x1=ts(c(5979511 ,13608701,  6193970 , 5269967 ,10424370 , 9504397),frequency=365.25/52)

#d<-cbind(as.data.frame(x1),reg[1:length(x1),])

ucm_Forecast=function(x,h,xreg){

  print(x)
  if (ncol(xreg)>=1){


    x<-x/10000
    d<-cbind(as.data.frame(x),xreg[1:length(x),])

    fit_ucm<- ucm(formula = x~a+b, data = d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 365.25/52)

    print("right before predict")
    print(xreg)

    indep <- paste(names(d)[2:3], collapse= "+")
    newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0("rep(NA,h) ~ ", 
                                          indep,
                                          "+ SSMtrend(2, Q =  list(fit_ucm$est.var.level,fit_ucm$est.var.slope))",
                                          "+ SSMcycle(365.25/52, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle)")
                                   ), 
                        H = fit_ucm$irr.var, data=as.data.frame(xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),]))
    fcst <- predict(fit_ucm$model, newdata=newdata1)

    #fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, xreg=xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),])
    print("right after predict")
    fcst<-fcst*10000
    print(fcst)

  } else {

    x=ts(filter(Model_Dataset,Category==Cat,Date<FcstDate)$`Gross Sales`)
    x<-x*10000
    x<-x/10000
    x<-ts(x)

    x
    fitucm<- ucm(formula = x~0, data = x, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 365.25/52)
    fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, n.ahead = h)
    fcst<-fcst*10000
    fcst
  }

  return(fcst)
}
```

Apart from all this, I cannot assure that the predictions are correct. I have doubts about if the level and slope component are being right modelled using the `SSMtrend` function. If anyone have a better information about how to model each component, any information is welcomed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your time and for the solution. The fourth prediction is negative..That's a problem. Can you tell me where you read the documentation?

Comment: Just use ```?SSModel``` and there you have all the documentation for each SSsomething and ```?ucm``` for the ```ucm``` model.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea why I got a negative forecast?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have figured out the right cycle of the models. I mean, in the question you state that the period of the ```SSModel``` is 365, but it should be 365.25/52 like the timeserie right? So changing the period in both models could improve the predictions. But I don't really know, maybe you should contact the authors of the ```KFAS``` or ```ucm``` library and ask if all it's right done.

Comment: Thank you. You spotted it right. I changed the 365 to 365.25/52 and I get positive predictions.

Comment: Can you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600077/error-while-executing-ucm-code-on-time-series ? I think you can help me with this. Thank you for your time.