# Error while executing ucm code on time series

Tags: r

Consider the following code. The invocation of ucm *without* the function wrapper works correctly. (See the comment "THE FOLLOWING STATEMENT WORKS CORRECTLY".) But the function call errors out with the error below. Can someone help me debug? In a way similar to how I scale the time series values before passing them to the stand-alone ucm function, I scale the time series values in the else part of the function which ends up being executed on invocation of the function, but yet I see this error.

```
 Error in is.SSModel(do.call(updatefn, args = c(list(inits, model), update_args)),  : 
      System matrices (excluding Z) contain NA or infinite values, covariance matrices contain values larger than 1e+07


 library(rucm)
    reg1<-data.frame()
    h<-4
    x<-ts(c(5979511 ,13608701,  6193970 , 5269967 ,10424370 , 9504397, 4564657, 5665863, 3435868,9845647,5454546,2454657),frequency=365.25/52)
    x<-x/100000
    print(x)
    # THE FOLLOWING STATEMENT WORKS CORRECTLY
    fit_ucm<- ucm(formula = x~0, data = x, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE,cycle=TRUE,cycle.period=365.52/52)

    u<-ucm_Forecast(x,h,reg1)   <-This call errors out
    u


    ucm_Forecast=function(x,h,xreg){

      if (ncol(xreg)>=1){

        xregFit=data.frame(xreg[1:length(x),],check.names=FALSE)
        x<-x/10000
        d<-cbind(data.frame(x=x),xregFit)
        independent <- paste0("`", names(d)[-1], "`", collapse = " + ")
        fit_ucm<- ucm(as.formula(paste0("`",names(d[1]),"` ~", independent)), data = d, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE, cycle = TRUE, cycle.period = 365.25/52)
        print("right before predict")



        newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0("rep(NA,h) ~ ", independent, 
                                              "+ SSMtrend(2, Q =  list(fit_ucm$est.var.level,fit_ucm$est.var.slope))",
                                              "+ SSMcycle(365.25/52, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle)")), H = fit_ucm$irr.var, data=as.data.frame(xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),]))
        fcst<-predict(fit_ucm$model, newdata=newdata1)

        #fcst<-predict(fitucm$model, xreg=xreg[(length(x)+1):(length(x)+h),])
        print("right after predict")
        fcst<-fcst*10000
        print(fcst)

      } else {
        x<-x/100000
        print(x)
        fit_ucm<- ucm(formula = x~0, data = x, level = TRUE, slope=TRUE,cycle=TRUE,cycle.period=365.52/52)


            newdata1 <- SSModel(as.formula(paste0("rep(NA,h) ~ ",  
                                              " SSMtrend(2, Q =  list(fit_ucm$est.var.level,fit_ucm$est.var.slope))",
                                              "+ SSMcycle(365.25/52, Q = fit_ucm$est.var.cycle)")), H = fit_ucm$irr.var)

        fcst<-predict(fit_ucm$model, newdata=newdata1, n.ahead = h)
        fcst<-fcst*100000
        fcst
      }

      return(fcst)
    }
```

Comment: Hello again! Sorry to say I couldn't reproduce the error. Have you tried resetting the R session? 
My results: 
    u<-ucm_Forecast(x,h,reg1)   #This call errors out
    Time Series:
    Start = 1 
    End = 2.56605065023956 
    Frequency = 7.02403846153846 
     [1] 0.0005979511 0.0013608701 
    u
    Time Series:
    Start = 2.70841889117043 
    End = 3.13552361396304 
    Frequency = 7.02403846153846 
               fit
    [1,]  9.536139
    [2,]  2.228632
    [3,]  5.207996
    [4,] 13.352123

Comment: @JaiPizGon Thank you. It now works for me the way I have written it. But when I use similar code in my main program (which I cannot paste here) I get the same error that I have pasted above. It just ignores the scaling. In any case, thank you for your help.